# How to join three heterogeneous sources using single joiner

Tags: transformation, informatica-powercenter, joiner

How to join three heterogeneous sources using single joiner sources? Maybe three flat files, references three different relational databases (Oracle, Teradata, SQL server) tables or one flat file, one oracle table, and one SQL server table.

We need to use only one joiner only, how can we implement this?

Comment: You can not do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 flat files then it's not possible to join 3 flat files sources with one joiner. As mentioned in Informatica [Joiner Transformation documentation](https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-data-integration/current-version/transformations/joiner-transformation.html). The joiner transformation joins 2 heterogeneous sources.

If you have 2 tables and 1 flat file, then you could use SQL override to join the 2 tables, then use single joiner to join.